# IE9 SVG displaying issue

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, overlay, z-index, transparent

I've been looking a lot information about IE and SVG online, but without much success. I want to load a map in svg format using a label type `<object>` because I do not want to use the plugin from Adobe. The reason is that with the Adobe plugin, style sheets do not work on my object (which contains the external SVG). However, if I put the map inside this tag, it is shown above context menus and with an opaque white background. I have already tested the `<embed>` tag with the "wmode = transparent" and that worked well with the Adobe SVG Viewer (but the CSS didn't work).

What can I do? Any ideas?

Chrome does it well:
[image]

But IE...
[image]
Thanks in advance!

The CSS:

```
path:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<div id="panelmapa" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 100%; height:100%">
        <object style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; margin-top:75px; 
                margin-bottom:100px; margin-right:50px; margin-left:30px;"
                id="mapasvg" data="<%= path %>/map.svg" name="MapaSVG"
                type="image/svg+xml">
        </object>-->
</div>
```

And finally, the svg (I created it with Inkscape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<?xml-stylesheet href="../../css/mapaSVG.css"?><svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   onload="iniciar(evt)"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 1024 860"
   id="svg5724"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.1 "
   sodipodi:docname="mapaSVG.svg">
  <script
     id="script3"
     type="text/javascript"
     src="mapEffects.js" />
  <defs
     id="defs5726">
    <filter
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="filter3879">
      <feGaussianBlur
         inkscape:collect="always"
         stdDeviation="8.9458125"
         id="feGaussianBlur3881" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.86831672"
     inkscape:cx="903.46039"
     inkscape:cy="429.12416"
     inkscape:current-layer="mapa"
     id="namedview5728"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1440"
     inkscape:window-height="838"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5730">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="mapa">
   ...
```

Regards

Comment: I can't post the complete view of the site but I've taken some screenshots that I think are clarifying. I'm going to modify the post or look for a website to upload the images. 1 second hehe

Comment: Done :). Thank you for your interest. The problem is that I do not know how to make the background transparent.

Comment: is the dropdown menu inside the svg file, or in the parent html document? Looks like the map background has a filter, IE9 doesn't support that. Need more details on the html document structure + at least the svg root + the element/CSS styles that is the map background.

Comment: Well the dropdown menu it's made with javascript, but outside the svg. What are you seeing is inside an iframe. I'm going to modify the post so you can check the headers from the svg and the root.

Comment: It seems I can't post more text, so I can tell you that you're right, there is a filter that manages the shadow around the map.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're asking three questions as I understand it.

1. Why is the background of the map white in IE9?
2. Why does the custom dropdown menu not render on top of the map?
3. Why does the object/iframe overlap some elements in the html document?

Some suggestions:

- Try without using a filter on the map.
- Try to make a minimal testcase, have you checked the positions and z-index of the elements you want to position on top of the object/iframe?
- Try adding a border to the object/iframe so that you see where it is and if it's the same as the map.
- Try setting background:red and background:transparent on the object/iframe element, perhaps white is the default background color in IE9?
- Try a good javascript/DOM debugger and test in more browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had my svg file inside the wrong <div>, but the problem persist. White background does not disappear. I've tryied with the z-index and setting color of the background without success. This is what I tried and I think the problem is IE and the way he manages SVG because I saw red background and transparent background of the div, but the svg bg remains white. The code: <div class="pagina" style="height:100%; width:100%; background:transparent;">
   <object id="mapasvg" data="mapaSVG.svg" name="MapaSVG"
     type="image/svg+xml">
   </object>
   </div>

Comment: Now I'm using raphael.js library and the map looks good. I know that it is VML but considering IE the single and final user, I'm going to leave SVG for now. Thank you so much for your interest. My conclussion it's that IE id the worst web explorer, cause firefox and chrome worked fine with my code. Regards!